# Check if the format of string matches desired format using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write code that will take a given string and compare it to a certain format.
This is what I'm using:

```
private static readonly Regex phoneNumber = new Regex(@"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}");

public static bool VerifyPhoneNumber(string pNumber)
{
    return phoneNumber.IsMatch(pNumber);
}
```

The format is `000-000-0000`, and it returns true when comparing it to `555-555-5555`. I also have a `MessageBox` displaying `pNumber` and `phoneNumber` for comparison purpose. The Message Box displays: `pNumber = 555-555-5555` and `phoneNumber = \d{3}-\d{3}\d{4}`

But that isn't the format I want. I want to use this format (000)000-0000. In order to use this format I changed phoneNumber to this:

```
private static readonly Regex phoneNumber = new Regex("(" + @"\d{3}" +  ")" + @"\d{3}-\d{4}");
```

But when I run this code and compare `(555)555-5555` to it, it returns false. The `MessageBox` for this displays: `pNumber = (555)555-5555` and `phoneNumber = (\d{3})\d{3}-\d{4}`

Now I don't know enough about `Regex` yet to fix this issue myself. Based on my research so far, the () are causing the issue. I believe its because () are used for regular expressions and dashes aren't. So, the dash doesn't mess anything up. My question is how can I change my code to fit my needs? How can I get the () in the code without issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape your parenthesies with `\(` and `\)`.

```
private static readonly Regex phoneNumber = new Regex(@"\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}");
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I figured it was something simple like this.

Answer (score 3):

"(" is special to regex. Make sure it has a backslash in front of it if you mean to match against a literal parenthesis.